# How to add minutes to a timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a table which has data in 5 minute intervals i.e. 5 10 15 20 ...

The table has 3 columns (id number, log_ts date , count number)  and has  millions of rows. So far I have been using the below query to sum up the "count" column for a particular date .

I need to aggregate on an **hourly** level

```
select id, SUM(count)
     log_ts + DECODE(TO_CHAR(log_ts , 'MI'), '05', 55/1440, '10', 50/1440, '15', 45/1440, '20',40/1440,'25',35/1440,'30',30/1440,'35',25/1440,'40',20/1440,'45',15/1440,'50',10/1440,'55',5/1440,0) TS
from example_table 
Group by id,
log_ts + DECODE(TO_CHAR(log_ts , 'MI'), '05', 55/1440, '10', 50/1440, '15', 45/1440, '20',40/1440,'25',35/1440,'30',30/1440,'35',25/1440,'40',20/1440,'45',15/1440,'50',10/1440,'55',5/1440,0)
```

Is there any other way to aggregate a time column at an hourly level which has data in 5 minutes level.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`TRUNC()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm#sthref1717), which can truncate a date/number etc to the unit of time specified.

For hourly, the [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions255.htm#i1002084) is `HH`. This makes your query:

```
select trunc(log_ts, 'HH'), sum(count)
  from example_table
 group by trunc(log_ts, 'HH')
```

I assume the name of your column isn't actually `COUNT`. If it is I would recommend changing this to something that isn't a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT id, trunc(log_ts, 'HH'), sum(count)
FROM   example_table
GROUP BY id, trunc(log_ts, 'HH');
```